# Acces to AWS EC2 from corporate network

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have a Windows EC2 instance and i would like to connect to it from nthe corporate network. unfortunately, firewalls block RDP.
Can you tell me please how to proceed to be able to connect to my instance from the office ?
Tahnks you,
regards
SZ

Comment: Ask IT to unlock it for you? If it's important for your work that should be no problem, or…?

Comment: @user322273 Please mark as answer, if this is what u wanted

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are talking about Windows Server rather than the new DaaS virtual desktops from Amazon, you can use [Remote Desktop Gateway](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd983941%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), which tunnels RDP through HTTPS.

It *is* possible to use the same virtual machine for both Remote Desktop and the Remote Desktop Gateway role.

Comment: thank you for uour prompt answer. have you please a step by step link or document which describe how to do ? tnaks a lot

Comment: @user322273 It's already linked in my answer!